# Split Database column value

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm fetching data from database. I'm saving my data in string format like this

> 23,32

while fetching data from database my output is like

> [{"transaction_id":"28,34"}]

but i want the out put in this format

> [{"transaction_id":"28"},{"transaction_id":"34"}]

I'm not able to find the proper solution

Comment: Please show the code you are using to fetch the database records.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to mutate the data you're getting back with access mutator like:

```
public function getTransactionIdAttribute()
{
    return //logic you want to apply to $this->transaction_id
}
```

But I suspect what you actually should do is set up your database relationship as many-to-many and make a join table that holds your transaction ids.